# Video player for Android that allows custom aspect ratio and supports MKV with DTS and AC3?

Tags: android, video, media-player, mkv

I need a video player that allows to user to defind aspect ratio of video (width:height) and supports MKV with DTS and AC3. I tried MX Player - it supports custom aspect ratio, but doesn't support DTS audio. I tried install codec ARM NEON, but it doesn't help.

Comment: i'm not entirely sure (which is why this isn't an answer) but VLC for Android should be able to do what you need.

Comment: @Mustafa AKTAŞ VLC doesn't allow to set your custom aspect ratio.